# Make directory with leading hyphen

Tags: unix, mkdir

Trying to `mkdir` with a leading hyphen in the name.

```
 mkdir -foo-
 mkdir '-foo-'
 mkdir `-foo-`
 mkdir `echo '-foo-'`
```

None of these work.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using `--` to disable further option parsing:

```
mkdir -- -foo
```

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
$ mkdir ./-dir
```

in order to specify the directory with the current dir prefixed. The same 'trick' can be used with all other command line utils (e.g. `rmdir`, `rm` etc.).

I perhaps wouldn't create such a directory, though, unless it's really necessary. It's a little counter-intuitive and may cause similar confusion for others in the future.

Comment: both answers worked. Alex got his answer in 1 minute faster :/